# Mysql query killing script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO `table` (`data`, `value`, `name`, `id`) VALUES ".$result."";

$result = "('1', '2', 'John', '123'), (...), ... (...);";
```

This is data I collect from various places, sometimes I end up with an extra column

```
$result = "('1', '2', '3', 'John', '123'), (...), ... (...);";
```

Which returns an error. The problem is that the query is inside a php loop. My script can run for 40/+  min (cron job).

Is there any way of "escaping" this error so that it doesn't kill the script?

Comment: could you please post the function(s) that return this result

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a check on the result of your mysql_query, something like:

```
$ret = mysql_query($sql);
if($ret === false)
{
     // Do something special upon error
}
// Continue executing
```

That gives you control over any unexpected MySQL issues.

Edit: Also note that you should not end your query with a semi-colon, as per the [mysql_query() documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).